# keyloog is not recognized react native , how can i solve this problem?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I create an apk in react native? I follow the documentation and I get the error "keyloog is not recognized", try to run that command also in my folder C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdkx.x.x_x \ bin let me create a keyloog but throw this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J33a.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

error occurred because `keystore` file is not found in the desired location. in-order to generate a production apk we need a `keystore` file . make sure you generate and update its credentials as in the following doc

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#setting-up-gradle-variables

or this native help https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing